# nginx node.js proxy 502

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a `node.js` server running on port 5000 behind `nginx` and after reading several posts, I'm still getting a `502` from `nginx`. When accessing `mydomain.com:5000` in a browser, everything works just fine. Can someone spot what I may be doing wrong here?

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:5000 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=3s;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate ssl/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```